# Class 'App\GraphQL\Query\GraphQL' not found Error although included in config/app - service provider and aliases

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, graphiql

Unable to process queries in graphql as included classes is reported as not found

I am using Laravel version 5.8.8 with graphql plugin provided by https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel

```
'GraphQL' => Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL::class


Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQLServiceProvider::class,
Graphiql\GraphiqlServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: Did you use composer to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the Facade in your `config.php`, but you're not yet referring to the facade when you try to access it within one of the files in `app/GraphQL/Query`.

After defining your namespace in the file you want to use the Facade from, you will have to add a use statement for your facade:

```
<?php
namespace App\GraphQL\Query;

use GraphQL;
// ...
```

If you don't, PHP tries to auto-resolve the namespace of the class call to whatever namespace you are in currently (hence the error about not being able to find `App\GraphQL\Query\GraphQL`).

Comment: Thank you, My class was renamed as GraphType